# Is it possible to clear or erase the changes made to an array using its instance object in another class c#?If so how?

Tags: c#-4.0

Is it possible to clear or erase the changes made to an array using its instance object in another class c#?If so how?

I actually wanted to erase all the changes made to the array at the end of the loop.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  So... you've updated some variables, and you want to undo those updates?  There's no "undo" in C#, or in any language I've ever used.  If you want to set something to a given value, you have to have that value somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to save the array in other variable? Then use that array instead the old array

You can set in the constructor function an use